# Corrupt xamarin assemblys after firebase integration

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried to integrate Firebase to my Xamarin.Android application. I did it by using their official documentation.

Since I installed the necessary extentions and nuget packages, a bunch of Xamarin assemblys is not correctly included anymore.

See this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/986IZ.png

Any hints what I could do to fix this problem?

Comment: I could not even install Firebase on a new blank project without getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: When you add these libraries, Did you try to clean the project and rebuild it?

Comment: @MikeMa yes, I did it a couple times

Comment: I could not reproduce this on my end. I think that it may be that your version of Xamarin Forms might depend on older versions of the support libraries that Xamarin.Firebase requires.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin released version 0.4.3 of Xamarin.Build.Download. Updating this assembly solved my problem. It was a known bug.